# showing Cannot set property 'innerHTML' in Elementor _content_template() method

Tags: javascript, elementor

I am developing a custom Elementor widget. Now, In `_content_template` method I can see all the array data in `settings.select_country`. I want to show all the array data to the `li` list item.

To do that I am using this code but showing me error:

```
<ul id="ul"></ul>       
<#
    settings.select_country.forEach( ( item, index ) => {
        document.getElementById("ul").innerHTML += item;
    });
#>
```

I can't understand what it's showing me innertHTML error message?

The error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Can you quote the error message?

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: Make extra sure that the JS actually run after the browser has rendered the `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `document.getElementById("ul")` is `null`, which means that at the time when your code runs, an item with the `id` of `ul` does not exist, it's either already removed, not yet created, or created with a different `id`. You will need to find what the correct element is, find it and use that at a point when it exists.

Comment: I understand but why it's not working in Elementor?

Comment: @Shibbir I think that Elementor does not render your ul yet when the code which expects its existence is running. You will need to check your generated HTML. Is there an element with the id of ul? If so, then your code ran too early.